# Including demo database in installation pack

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, testing, installation

I have a C# program which is using Sql Server 2008 R2 to store data.
I have a problem with deploying the application, because I want to include a demo database in the installation pack, so that its easier for users to test.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not simple. Your installer will have to install SQL Server, possibly a silent install. But the machine may already have it installed. In which case they will not want you to uninstall it but instead use that install.

An easier approach might be to require that the `Sql Server 2008 R2` is already installed, ask for it's connection properties and create your **schema** in that instance during the install.

Comment: The program checks if Sql server is installed, if its not install Im doing a silent installation.. Do you have any example how I can include the demo database in the installation pack?

Comment: @Roi84 - Install the schema when the application is launched the first time.

Comment: Either at startup or in the install. I don't know Sql Server. It may be possible to deploy a pre-packaged db file, generating schema is the more popular approach I believe.

Comment: It can be done. I've seen it done. This page may be usefull: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264562%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Can you consider installing/using the SQL Server Compact Edition, just for the demo database? Presumably the demo data will be small and it would be straightforward to add the CE edition to your regular setup.